# Clear the "Invalid" flag on flags for posts that are subsequently removed by a moderator

Tags: discussion, feature-request

If I flag an answer as "not an answer" and Moderator X (whomever that may be) deems that flag invalid, the flag shows in my flagging summary as "Invalid".

If I later look at my flagging summary and see that the answer concerned has been deleted, by Moderator Y (*Note: For all I know, X and Y could be one and the same, that's irrelevant*) presumably as the result of flags from further users **without the original answer having been changed**, it would seem reasonable for my original flag to have its "Invalid" status cleared.

I'd suggest that a flag which is "cleared" wouldn have a neutral overall affect on a users overall weighting, i.e. it's excluded from calculating flag weight, rather than the -10 it garners as an invalid flag or the value between 10 and somewhere near 0 it gets as a valid flag.

Comment: It is possible to flag a post for a problem *incorrectly*, but some action is still required. Thus the flag is actually invalid even though some action was taken. An edge case, probably, but something to consider.

Comment: I would have thought this is a rather infrequent edge case, if it is happening regularly then surely one's flag weight ought to go down as you are flagging incorrectly?

Comment: @slugster - I'd agree that it's rather infrequent, but if this specific scenario (one moderator *disagrees* with your flag on a post and then another moderator *agrees* with another flag on the same post) occurs, its surely better to neutralise the invalid flag. If there was no such thing as "flag weight" then it'd be a non-issue, but, as soon as you start measuring things any perception of "unfairness" can have a negative impact. After all, we **want** people to flag, right? =)

Comment: Should we subsequently clear the *validated* flags on posts that were originally closed, but then another moderator reopens the post because the closure was erroneous? Making the future acts of other flaggers affect your already-resolved flag weight can be a slippery slope.